# Angular 2 Material: How to force align elements in modal?

Tags: html, css, angular-material2

Is there a way in Angular 2 Material force align (say a chip with very long text) and not mess up with the form element under it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIcvi.jpg)

[image: brokenLayout]

Comment: seems like a margin issue as these tags have margin on left and right. You can adjust that and it will align to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by declaring a fixed width upon opening the dialog.

```
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {  
            width: '250px'
        });
```